# SQL View Attributes

Tags: sql

There is a view that has been created in the database, referencing columns of other tables in the same database. How I can find the sources of columns within the view?

For example, `Info_View` has 4 columns: `Name`,`Surname`, `Job` and `Hobby`. These columns bind from different tables. How can I know which column comes from where?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? E.g. SQL Server, Postgre, Oracle, MySQL, etc? Please **tag** your question with the appropriate DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT view_name, Table_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE View_Name = '<giveViewName>'
ORDER BY view_name, table_name
```

got it from [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1638/using-sql-server-meta-data-to-list-tables-that-make-up-views/)

Answer (score 0):

for sql server

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38560/Overview-of-View-in-SQL-Server-2005

for postgresql

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createview.html

for mysql

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx